# Trying to port a GLSL glass shader to Processing 3.0

Tags: glsl, shader, processing

**EDITED**

I am beginner on Processing language and GLSL shaders. I am trying to port a fresnel+cubemap shader for a glass material. But as result my shape ever disappear, instead... :-(

My vertex shader is:

```
const float Air = 1.0;
const float Glass = 1.51714;

const float Eta = Air / Glass;

const float R0 = ((Air - Glass) * (Air - Glass)) / ((Air + Glass) * (Air + Glass));

uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat4 modelview;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

attribute vec4 vertex;
attribute vec3 normal;

varying vec3 v_reflection;
varying vec3 v_refraction;
varying float v_fresnel;

void main(void){

    vec4 t_vertex = modelview * vertex;

    vec3 incident = normalize(vec3(t_vertex));

    vec3 t_normal = normalMatrix * normal;

    v_refraction = refract(incident, t_normal, Eta);
    v_reflection = reflect(incident, t_normal);

    v_fresnel = R0 + (1.0 - R0) * pow((1.0 - dot(-incident, t_normal)), 5.0);

    gl_Position = transform * t_vertex;
}
```

And the fragment shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
precision mediump int;
#endif

uniform samplerCube cubemap;

varying vec3 v_refraction;
varying vec3 v_reflection;
varying float v_fresnel;

void main(void){
    vec4 refractionColor = textureCube(cubemap, normalize(v_refraction));
    vec4 reflectionColor = textureCube(cubemap, normalize(v_reflection));

    gl_FragColor = mix(refractionColor, reflectionColor, v_fresnel);
}
```

I am testing this shader with the Processing 3.0 sketch bellow (**edited**), on Android Mode:

```
PShader shader;
PShape sphere;

void setup() {
  fullScreen(P3D);
  noStroke();

  shader = loadShader("glass.frag.glsl", "glass.vert.glsl");
  openCubeMap("posx.png", "negx.png", "posy.png", "negy.png", "posz.png", "negz.png");
  shader.set("cubemap", 1);

  sphere = createShape(SPHERE, 120);
  sphere.setFill(color(-1, 50));
} 

void draw() {
  background(0);      

  directionalLight(102, 102, 102, 0, 0, -1);
  lightSpecular(204, 204, 204);
  directionalLight(102, 102, 102, 0, 1, -1);
  specular(100, 150, 150);

  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  shader(shader);
  shape(sphere);
}  

void openCubeMap(String posX, String negX, String posY, String negY, String posZ, String negZ) {

  PGL pgl = beginPGL();
  // create the OpenGL-based cubeMap
  IntBuffer envMapTextureID = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
  pgl.genTextures(1, envMapTextureID);
  pgl.activeTexture(PGL.TEXTURE1);
  pgl.enable(PGL.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);  
  pgl.bindTexture(PGL.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, envMapTextureID.get(0));
  pgl.texParameteri(PGL.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, PGL.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, PGL.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  pgl.texParameteri(PGL.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, PGL.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, PGL.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  pgl.texParameteri(PGL.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, PGL.TEXTURE_WRAP_R, PGL.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  pgl.texParameteri(PGL.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, PGL.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, PGL.LINEAR);
  pgl.texParameteri(PGL.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, PGL.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, PGL.LINEAR);

  //Load in textures
  String[] textureNames = { posX, negX, posY, negY, posZ, negZ };
  for (int i=0; i<textureNames.length; i++) {    
    PImage texture = loadImage(textureNames[i]);
    int w = texture.width;
    int h = texture.height;
    texture.loadPixels();
    pgl.texImage2D(PGL.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, PGL.RGBA, w, h, 0, PGL.RGBA, PGL.UNSIGNED_BYTE, IntBuffer.wrap(texture.pixels));
  }

  endPGL();
}
```

And I am using [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-KFG7c6SvVZVmY2MEFuZDBRa2s) images to build the cubemap.

Someone know how I can make this work?

Comment: That's a lot of code to ask us to go through. You'll probably have better luck if you post a [mcve] by narrowing it down to as few lines as possible.

Comment: You are totally right, sorry. The previous post was a little confusing. Please check my edited question.

The relevant parts are the vertex and frag code. But I added the sketch code to help, and cleaned up.

Sorry if is still so much lines, but I am afraid to sacrifice some clarity if I reduce it more. 

Thanks for help and advise, @Kevin Workman.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is not in your code but in your data.

OpenGL requires that all textures used by the cubemap have the **same dimensions**, and that the textures be **square** otherwise it will refuse to load it.

I checked your PNGs and this is not the case, they all have the same dimension but they are not square (255x230).

Also for Android it may be required that the **texture dimensions be a power of 2** (128, 256, 512 ...)

So I tested resizing all the textures to 256x256 pixels and now your sample works :

[image: it works !]